# Django 1.5 DatabaseError at / (1146 , "Table 'x.y' doesn't exist")

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm facing this error:

```
DatabaseError at / (1146 , "Table 'mycompany_db.mycompany_table' doesn't exist")
```

For this Project, I'm running **Python 2.7**, **Django 1.5** and **MySQL 5.26** (and I cannot change or upgrade my stack for a while).

All the dependecies are already installed via **pip**.

Here is my **settings.py** (snippet):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mycompany_db',         
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'development',   
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',    
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

The **console** shows me:

```
Failed to submit message: u'DatabaseError: (1146, "Table \'mycompany_db.mycompany_table\' doesn\'t exist")'
```

Of course, before running the development server, I already ran **syncdb** and **migrate**.

So, what should I do in order to resolve this?

Gratitude,

Comment: Try `makemigration` and then `migrate`.

Comment: @Darius do `makemigrations` works under Django 1.5?

Comment: Django migrations are for Django 1.7+. With earlier versions of Django, you can use [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). The equivalent command in South is [`schemamigration`](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html#schemamigration).

Answer (score 0):

Syncdb will not create joining tables for many to many fields. You can create the table with a migration (with South for Django < 1.7), or by running the create table statements manually.

You can see the SQL required to create the table with the sqlall command.

```
./manage.py sqlall yourapp
```

Since you haven't shown your model, and you have censored the error messages, it's not possible to give any more specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

You database settings seems to be ok. You can try by drope all tables manually and run syncdb again.